# Is there a way to automatically retrieve the HTML tag and attributes of a highlighted element on a web page?

Tags: html, firebug

I need to retrieve the HTML tags along with their attribute values of a particular highlighted element in a web page automatically into a file, so that I can use them in my Watir test automation.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by 'highlighted element'? I don't know about Watir but its [cheat sheet](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#wiki-accessing-an-element) indicates that you can easily access different HTML elements with it.

Comment: When hovered over a particular element, html trackers like *firebug, highlight the html code/tag related to the element. I need to find a way, through which I can automatically retrieve the attribute name and values for that particular tag into my Watir/Ruby code.

Comment: And why do you need Firebug for this? As I wrote in my previous comment you can get all information about an element directly using Watir. Or do you want to get the information about the highlighting added by Firebug?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the information highlighted by the firebug tool in a html page